# Periodic solution to $y\prime = ay + b(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

I'm a bit stuck on a certain review question for ODEs. Here's how it goes:

Given the one dimensional equation $y\prime(x) = ay+b(x)$, with $a\neq 0$ and $b:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ continuous and $T$-periodic, prove that there exists a unique $T$-periodic solution.

Now, I know that the flux of this particular equation can be explicitly written as: $$\varphi(x;x_0,k) = ke^{a(x-x_0)} + \int_{x_0}^x{b(s)e^{a(x-s)}ds}$$

(This is, each solution to the IVP $y(x_0) = k$)

So I figure I can prove existence by choosing adequate $x_0$ and $k$ (my intuition indicates $k = 0$), such that I can prove  periodicity, and uniqueness will be "for-free" by Picard's theorem. I've tried writing the above expression at $x$ and $x+T$ and equating, but I haven't gotten anywhere really. Maybe this isn't the right approach anyway. Can someone help?

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, I meant $ay$

Comment: You might re-check your formula for $\varphi(x; x_0, k)$.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis How do you mean? I think it's correct.

Comment: Try computing $d\varphi / dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint: because you are looking for periodic solution you may as well take $x_0 = 0.$
the integral representation of the solution then 
$$ y(T) = y(0) = y(0)e^{aT} +\int_0^T b(s)e^{a(T-s)} \ ds $$ which gives you 
the constraint
$$(e^{-aT}-1)y(0) = \int_0^T b(s)e^{-as} \ ds $$

Comment: Ah, alright this solves it, thanks. I guess I was almost there actually. By the way, I assume your $dx$ are $ds$.

Comment: @GPerez, thanks. yes you were almost there. i have fixed the  dx.

Comment: In what sense does this solve the problem?

Comment: @RobertLewis, it gives you a constraint on the initial value  $y(0)$ to have a periodic solution. do you have a better idea?

Comment: Not sure . . . maybe . . .  will try to get back to you on it . . . meanwhile, you might check your formula for $\varphi(x: x_0, k)$; see my comments above.  We'll get it!  Happy New Year!

Comment: @RobertLewis It works: to simplify, first write $y(x) = ke^{a(x-x_0)} + e^{ax}\int_{x_0}^x{b(s)e^{-as}ds}$, since the integration variable is $s$. When you differentiate you get $dy/dx = ake^{a(x-x_0)} + e^{ax}b(x)e^{-ax} + ae^{ax}\int_{x_0}^xb(s)e^{-as} = a(ke^{a(x-x_0)} + \int_{x_0}^xb(s)e^{a(x-s)}) +b(x)$.

Comment: @RobertLewis I still am interested in an alternative approach, possibly just working with the ODE itself. It would be more "realistic" seeing as I'll rarely ever have the explicit solution at hand in other cases. I was unable to come up with one though.